# filter out dates that have already passed

Tags: php

Need some help here.  I am nearly done, but stuck on how to filter out dates in the past.  For example, I dont want dates from yesterday to appear as an otpion.  Below is my code so far.

```
 <select name="choose_date" id="choose_date">
 <?php
    if (isset($datesavailable) && is_array($datesavailable))
    {
      foreach($datesavailable as $val)
      {
        rsort($val);
        echo' <option value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'</option>\n';
      }
    }
  ?>
  </select>
```

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: what format are the dates in?

Comment: Please post `var_dump($datesavailable)`

Comment: wrong place for the filtering. how do you generate the dates in the first place?

Comment: complete php code [link] http://pastebin.com/8C7T6dcw  . Dates in DB Are yyy-mm-dd. The page is a wordpress site if that helps at all

Comment: it doesnt show how you get $datesAvailable.

Comment: sorry this was in the function.php file  $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_location_date WHERE location=$id ORDER BY location_date");

Answer (score 1):

Compare the unix timestamp of the "today" date and a given date... (the format you use for your dates should not be critical as strtotime will parse a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp)

```
$date = "2004-02-29";
$unix_date = strtotime ($date);

if ($unix_date < time() ) 
{ 
  echo "date is before"; 
}
else 
{ 
  echo "date is after"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to convert dates to unix timestamp and compare it to time() or similar function (depends on timezone, etc.). Also you can try using `strtotime`, but it is pretty syntax depending. Imagine that you have correct syntax (something like `Y-m-d H:i`):

```
foreach ($datesavailable as $val) {
  if (!(strtotime($val) < time()))
    echo ' <option value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'</option>\n';
}
```

Also I can't understand why is there `rsort($val);`? `rsort` is array's reverse sorting function, why do you try sort the string?

And finally, you should consider about to filter data much before the output, e.g. on selecting data.

Comment: here is a link to the  complete code on pastebin.com [link]http://pastebin.com/8C7T6dcw[link]

Comment: It does not change anything, I've already posted my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP 5.3 you can use the DatePeriod class to generate the available dates, say you want to include only the next month:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$lastDay = clone $today;
$lastDay->add(new DateInterval("P1M1D"));
$period = new DatePeriod($today, new DateInterval("P1D"), $lastDay);

foreach ($period as $day)
{
    $formatted = $day->format('Y-m-d');
    print "<option value=\"{$formatted}\">{$formatted}</option>\n";
}
```

You'll have to set the default timezone with date_default_timezone_set()

Answer (score 1):

Now that we have more information I'll give another answer but I'll leave my first one here in case it may help someone with other problems.

Given the new information, why not filter the old dates already when fetching the dates from the database? The query would then be:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_location_date WHERE location=$id and location_date >= CUR_DATE() ORDER BY location_date
```

and judging by the use of rsort() function you want the available dates in reverse order so the query could fix this immediately by adding DESC after the order by, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_location_date WHERE location=$id and location_date >= CUR_DATE() ORDER BY location_date DESC
```

If you still must do this in PHP, you can filter the dates like this:

```
// Have this first line outside the foreach(), no need to set it multiple times.
$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$valDate = strtotime($val);

if ($valDate >= $today)
{
    echo ' <option value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'</option>\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon points out, you should remove undesired dates while constructing `datesavailable`, but you can do that either here or before with something as simple as:

```
if (strtotime($val) < strtotime('today')) {
   continue;
}
```

You can get more specific, but `strtotime` may not work depending upon what your dates look like.

Comment: I think you are close, but didnt seem to fix. complete code is here [link]http://pastebin.com/8C7T6dcw There is ajax at the top of the page too.